# How to get random objects from a stream and return it

Tags: java, random, stream

I have List with some users from google and now in stream I say for every google user make new HRVacationUser ( witch is model ) and give me ( their email, some random date, some random date ) which random date is for random holiday. But in that case i set each user is on vacantion. How can I take random user from google users and set random date for holiday, so I can make a request in the database - give me this user which is in holiday?

My List /GoogleUser> is with size for example 80, and I want to set only for random users vacantion date, and then to make request if(user is in vacantion return 'user') and in database to do request give me holiday users

```
public List<HRVacationUser> listVacationGoogleUsers(List<GoogleUser> allGoogleUsers){
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        List<HRVacationUser> collectHRUser = allGoogleUsers.stream()
                .map(user ->
                        new HRVacationUser(user.getPrimaryEmail(), date.minusDays(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,5)), date.plusDays(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5))))
                .collect(toList());
        return collectHRUser;
    }
```

Comment: You collect them to a ``List``. Generate a random number as list index, then modify the user behind ``collectHRUser.get(randomIndex)``.

Comment: To solve the first part of your question have a look on this question: [How to get random objects from a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703226/how-to-get-random-objects-from-a-stream)

Comment: `Collections.shuffle(list)` before return of `collectHRUser`

Comment: Yes, but this is not like my problem. My allGoogleUsers list is with size for example 80, and I want to set only for random users vacantion date, and then to make request if(user is in vacantion return 'user') and in database to do request give me holiday users :)

Comment: You'd better provide a **minimal** demo to elaborate your idea? What **exactly** you wanna achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a random item from your list, based on your list size:

```
import java.util.Random;

List<?> yourList = new ArrayList<>();
yourList.get(new Random().nextInt(yourList.size()));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the random library

```
import java.util.Random;
```

More possible solutions for random elements [here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-return-a-random-item-from-a-list/) =)